# How can I create files , read and write files in Python?

Tags: python

All the tutorials I can find follow the same format which isn't working.I don't get an error message but I don't get normal output. What I get appears to be the file description at some memory location.

# file_test

```
ftpr= open("file","w")
ftpr.write("This is a sample line/n")
a=open("file","r")
print a




#This is the result

<open file 'file', mode 'r' at 0x00000000029DDDB0>
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to read the contents of the file? Try `print a.readlines()`.

Ie:

```
with open('file', 'w') as f:
  f.write("Hello, world!\nGoodbye, world!\n")

with open('file', 'r') as f:
  print f.readlines()  # ["Hello, world!\n", "Goodbye, world!\n"]
```

---

FYI, the [with blocks](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html), if you're unfamiliar with them, ensure that the `open()`-d files are `close()`-d.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to read the file. You are printing return value from open call  which is object of file type. Do like this for reading and writing.

## for writing

f=open("myfile","w")

f.write("hello\n")

f.write("This is a sample line/n")

f.close()

## For reading

f=open("file","r")

string = f.read()

print("string")

f.close()